# Select text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [Prism.js](http://prismjs.com) to do some syntax highlighting. Now Prism.js generates a `<code>` div with lots of children `divs` to do highlighting and placing the actual code (or text) as inner texts of those divs.

My question is, using jQuery how can I get the rendered `<code>` tag highlighted (as in selected), similar to the manual mouse drag and selecting of texts inside a textbox.

I have tried `$(el).select();` but it did not work.

Comment: "manual manual mouse drag" ?

Comment: yes, drag into a text and it gets selected

Comment: This might question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse