# Select text with GWT

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

This is the [suggested answer from the Javascript SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191562/select-text-with-jquery) I have modified it to make it a JSNI:

```
Element content = DOM.createElement("code");
select(content);

public static native void select(Element el)/*-{
    var doc =  $wnd.document
        , text = $wnd.$(el)
        , range, selection
    ;
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        range = $wnd.document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    } else if ($wnd.window.getSelection) {
        selection = $wnd.window.getSelection();
        range = $wnd.document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}-*/;
```

However when used, it throws:

```
caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : Argument 1 of Range.selectNodeContents does not implement interface Node.
```

What could be wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the `id` of your element which you can use in the Javascript code to acquire the respective HTML element, and pass this element to your `selectNodeContents()` javascript function:

```
// Call it like this:
select(el.getId());

// And the modified select:
public static native void select(String elId)/*-{
    // ...OTHER CODE OMITTED
    range.selectNodeContents($wnd.document.getElementById(elId));
    // ...OTHER CODE OMITTED
}-*/;
```